# URL without file extension working without mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, file-extension

On my server, when I access the file `http://example.com/file.php` with the URL `http://example.com/file`, it still displays the correct file, although I have no .htaccess with any URL rewriting.

Can I rely on this to work across all (current) browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have mod_negotiation / Options +MultiViews in your httpd configuration. The kind of negotiation you describe shouldn't have any browser dependency.

Comment: Thank you. I'm on a shared server and have no access to the httpd configuration file. Is there any way to find out what those settings are?